# Intelli J keep trying download gradle src.zip despite of setting local gradle

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, build

I’m a user which Intelli J 2023.2 Ultimate Edition.

I made a project based on Spring boot and Gradle.
And I set gradle-wrapper and gradle-6.9.2-bin.zip on local.

My application network environment is closed network. And I'm using nexus for managing dependencies.

For using nexus repositories, I had to set a online mode in Intelli J gradle option.

In this situation, Intelli J keep trying download gradle-6.9.2-src.zip. And I got a error message like below.

```
"Could not get resource 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.9.2-src.zip'"
```

My network is closed, so Intelli J can't access there. This network envrionmet can't be changed.

I don't know why Intelli J try to download gradle-src.zip despite I already download and set gralde-bin.zip in gradle-wrapper.properties.

I tried to change below intelli J option, but it couln't be changed. (It couldn't be saved)

```
Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle: 
Change "Distribution" value to 'Local installation' and I put location value which gralde-bin.zip. But it was not saved.
```

This problem is not only 2023.2 Ultimate but also 2023.2 Community edition.

Does Anyone know this problem solution? Please help me.

Comment: If you are looking to use a local install of Gradle you have to point IDEA to the extracted Gradle distribution, i.e. directory that contains "bin", "init.d" and "lib" directories.

Comment: If you are looking to use the Wrapper, check [Your Project Directory] -> gradle -> wrapper -> gradle-wrapper.properties file and update distributionUrl. Alternatively, you can just put gradle-wrapper.jar to  [Your Project Directory] -> gradle -> wrapper (for instance if you have the wrapper in one of your other Projects.

Comment: @romanv-jb Thank you for your answer. But your guides are not working for me. 

I set a local install of gradle directory which has bin, init.d and lib, but Intelli J still try to connect external gradle src zip download url. Also despite I set distributionUrl in my gradle-wrapper.properties which in my project directory gradle wrapper, It also keep trying to access gradle src download url. 
My network is closed network, but I have to use Nexus repository in closed network. So I have to use gradle online mode. 
Could you give me other guides for solving it?

Comment: Further discussion: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/16134282733074-Intelli-J-keep-trying-download-gradle-src-zip-despite-of-setting-local-gradle